# What is Interaction Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've noticed that a new **Interaction Studio** app has magically appeared in our Marketing Cloud account today.

[image]

There's no documentation on this (at least I can't find any) and there aren't any [release notes](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/) either. I note that existing Interactions (created in Journey Builder) don't appear in this app. I'd be grateful if someone could enlighten me exactly what this new app is for.

Does this replace Journey Builder? It appears to. That is, you can build and run an Interaction directly from Interaction Studio without the need for Journey Builder. However, I note that Interactions that I create in this app are available in Journey Builder. So, perhaps this isn't the end of Journey Builder. At least, for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been informed that Interaction Studio is Journey Builder's predecessor. That makes sense. But I swear it wasn't available in our account, until now.

Answer (score 1):

[Interaction Studio](https://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/stories/2018/6/061318-g/) does not replace Journey Builder. It is similar to journey builder in that it can be omni-channel (email, social, mobile, etc.), but differs in that it reacts to real-time behaviors of consumers in those channels.

> For example, if a consumer clicks on a certain offer from a brand and
>   then logs into the mobile app or calls the service center, Interaction
>   Studio instantly updates individual consumer engagement profiles with
>   those real-time actions. With that context, Marketing Cloud can
>   deliver the next best experience — such as relevant promotions,
>   discounts or other content — at any moment as consumers engage with
>   the brand.

Interaction Studio is a [real-time interaction management](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/customer-interaction/) tool and Journey Builder is just one aspect of Interaction Studio.

Comment: This is an old question. The original Interaction Studio (refer to screenshot) is now end-of-life. However, just to add confusion, Salesforce decided to re-use the product name when they white labelled Thunderhead One.

Answer (score -1):

When we started using ExactTarget in July 2013, Automation Studio has just been turned on for accounts, and was in ours. It was described to me by my on-boarding guide that it was a brand new alternative to Programs. And personally, I find it much easier and more user-friendly to use than Programs, or when sending any complex or timed sends. I use it frequently.

Comment: Hi, I'm aware of Automation Studio, we use this regularly too. Interaction Studio is a completely different app. It turns out that this was provisioned on our production account by mistake and it's been removed now.