# What is Interaction Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, roles, interaction

Iam about to configure roles and permissions now i saw a fuction called  "INTERACTION STUDIO"
what is the so called "Interaction Studio" I never heard of it before!

Could you kindly explain?

Thank you

Comment: I think you can find your answer here, possibly duplicate question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/65802/what-is-interaction-studio

Answer (score 2):

Interaction Studio was the old name for Journey Builder. You'll still see it referred to its old name in certain places in the UI, documenation and API.

Comment: Alright Thank you. Confusing for our customer why it is still mentioned in the role concept.